# Where is the option to turn on Intel vt-x

Tags: windows-8, emulator, android-studio, intel-haxm

I am trying to develop for android and I use emulator to test my applications.
The emulator does not start in Android Studio unless **HAXM** or **Intel atom x86** is installed on the computer.
I downloaded **HAXM** and installed it but it shows that to install **HAXM** I need to turn on something called **Intel vt-x**. From where it can be turned on in **Windows 8**.

I tried the emulator of eclipse but it is not fast enough to satisfy me.

Answer (score 1):

VT-X is usually enabled at BIOS level. Check the manual of your mainboard, it should contain instructions on how to access BIOS settings and VT-X options.

The exact steps may vary depending on your mainboard manufacturer, but in case you need further assistance [this guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/213795/how-to-enable-intel-vt-x-in-your-computers-bios-or-uefi-firmware/) might be useful.

Of course, your CPU has to support VT-X. Check the manual or product website of your CPU to find out if it does. In case it does not, you will not be able to turn it on anywhere. *Thanks to Moab for [pointing this out](https://superuser.com/questions/1046770/where-is-the-option-to-turn-on-intel-vt-x#comment1465908_1046776).*

Comment: If the processor supports vt-x, it may be enabled in the bios, otherwise, no it cannot.